# Laravel : How to do a where clause on the first result of a wherehas (order by)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For this new year, I have a problem with Eloquent:

I have an *EtabInvariant* Model with a relationship on an *EtabVariant* Model like this (orderBy):

```
class EtabInvariant extends Model
{   
   
    // I've deleted this part because it's a big table...

    public function etab_variant()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EtabVariant::class, 'ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre')->orderBy('ev_debut_annee_scolaire','desc');
    }
}
```

In my controller, I'd like to do a where clause on the first result of *etab_variant*.

The following code works but the where clause is applied on every results of *etab_variant*.

```
class VisiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
       $q = EtabInvariant::with(['etab_variant']);
       $nbClasses = 13; // This is an input property in the real app
       $q->whereHas('etab_variant', function($query) use ($nbClasses) {
         $query->where('ev_nb_classes', $nbClasses);
       });
       return response()->json($q->get(), 200);
    {
}
```

I'd like to apply the where clause only on the first result of the whereHas (because etab_variant was orderBy and only the first result interest me)
So, I've tried many things but nothing works.

```
// This doesn't work
// I guess it's because find() return a collection or something like that...
$query->first()->where('ev_nb_classes', $nbClasses);
```

If someone could help me, it would be a Christmas miracle!
Thank you folks and happy new year!

Florent

---

### EDIT (following @lagbox answer)

If I use the **hasMany** relationship, the result of my controller is something like that (I've deleted all the superfluous information):

```
[
    {
        "ei_uai_nombre": 140545,
        "etab_variant": [
        {
            "ev_debut_annee_scolaire": 2020,
            "ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre": 140545,
            "ev_nb_classes": 10
        },
        {
            "ev_debut_annee_scolaire": 2019,
            "ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre": 140545,
            "ev_nb_classes": 8
        }]
    },
    {
        "ei_uai_nombre": 140691,
        "etab_variant": [
        {
            "ev_debut_annee_scolaire": 2020,
            "ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre": 140691,
            "ev_nb_classes": 5
        },
        {
            "ev_debut_annee_scolaire": 2019,
            "ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre": 140691,
            "ev_nb_classes": 7
        }]
    }
]
```

If I use the **hasOne** relationship, as suggested by @lagbox in the answers, the code is the following:

```
    public function etab_variant_latest()
    {
        // Seul le résultat le plus récent sera renvoyé
        return $this->hasOne(EtabVariant::class, 'ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre')->orderBy('ev_debut_annee_scolaire','desc');
    }
```

and the result of my controller is something like that:

[
{
"ei_uai_nombre": 140545,
"etab_variant_latest": {
"ev_debut_annee_scolaire": 2020,
"ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre": 140545,
"ev_nb_classes": 10
}
},
{
"ei_uai_nombre": 140691,
"etab_variant_latest": {
"ev_debut_annee_scolaire": 2020,
"ev_fk_ei_uai_nombre": 140691,
"ev_nb_classes": 5
}
}
]

SO, it's nearly works: the controller returns the latest 'etab_variant' for each row.
THE PROBLEM is that the where clause applies to all the 'etab_variant' in each result. For instance, if the where clause is 'ev_nb_classes>6', the result is the same that the one above (ev_nb_classes value is 5 in 2020 but it was 7 in 2019).

I'd like to apply the where clause only on the latest etab_variant (it's 2020 in the above example)

I don't know if I'm clear enought... Don't hesitate to tell me if you need other explications.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correct, you want to get the first `etab_variant` where the condition `ev_nb_classes = $nbClasses` evaluates to true.

You can do that by constraining the eager load

```php
$q = EtabInvariant::with([
    'etab_variant' => fn($q) => $q->where('ev_nb_classes', $nbClasses)->limit(1)
]);
```

For PHP < 7.4

```php
$q = EtabInvariant::with([
    'etab_variant' => function($q){
        $q->where('ev_nb_classes', $nbClasses)->limit(1);
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not exactly what I'm looking for because I need to order 'etab_variant' before to evaluate the where clause.

Comment: I've tried your answer to see what it would done but it throws an error : `ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'`

Comment: @LUCASFlorent Have updated the answer for PHP < 7.4 as it seems that the arrow function is throwing an error for you. However would suggest you to upgrade the PHP version to at least 7.4 since PHP 7.3 is now EOL

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create another relationship which is the `HasOne` version of your `HasMany` relationship:

```
public function etab_variant()
{
    return $this->hasOne(EtabVariant::class, ...)->orderBy(...);
}

// the current relationship renamed to plural since it is a has many
public function etab_variants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EtabVariant::class, ...)->orderBy(...);
}
```

Then you can use what you have since what you have uses the `etab_variant` relationshp which is now the `HasOne`.

```
EtabInvariant::with('etab_variants')->whereHas('etab_variant', ...)...
```

Comment: Thank you, it nearly works! However, there is a strange problem: the whereHas clause applies to all the etab_variant and not to the latest one. I'll edit my question to explain more.